# How does this program continuously update and print the time from struct time in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, struct, time, while-loop

I am studying a program that continuously updates the time and I have some questions on how it works.

When I comment out the while(1) loop, the program still runs but does not print the time. Why is the while loop needed? Isn't it a bad idea to make a while loop that always proceeds? Does the continuous while loop run the if loop every second?

From the line that stores total seconds to time(0), what data type is time(0)? Is it an int? If so, why is it followed by (0)? If I change the 0 to a 1, the following error appears:

```
C:\Users\Roman Justice\Desktop\Clock_1.cpp  In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Roman Justice\Desktop\Clock_1.cpp  [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'time_t* {aka long long int*}' [-fpermissive]
```

Is this error saying that time_t total_seconds is being converted to long long int?

What is the meaning of the line that reads "seconds=ct->tm_sec;"? Does this convert a part of struct time to a readable or printable format?

For the if statement, I am confused by the lines "sec_prev=seconds;" and "seconds==sec_prev+1". The first line assigns sec_prev to seconds, so does that mean they will always be the same? In the cout statement, why are the times coded as ("hours<10?"0":"") and not just "hours"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int sec_prev=0;

    while(1)
    {
    int seconds, minutes, hours;
    string str;

    //storing total seconds
    time_t total_seconds=time(0);

    //getting values of seconds, minutes, hours
    struct tm* ct=localtime (&total_seconds);

    seconds=ct->tm_sec;
    minutes=ct->tm_min;
    hours=ct->tm_hour;

    //converting it into 12 hour format
    if (hours>=12)
       str="PM";
    else
       str="AM";

    hours=hours>12?hours-12:hours; 

    //printing the result
    if(seconds==sec_prev+1 || (sec_prev==59 && seconds==0)) 
        {
        system("CLS");
        cout << (hours<10?"0":"") << hours <<":" << 
        (minutes<10?"0":"") << minutes << ":" << (seconds<10?"0":"") << 
        seconds << " " << str << endl; 
        }

    sec_prev=seconds;

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make up your mind, whether the `while` loop is `while(1)` as described, or `while(0)` as shown. Please show real code, logically indented, instead of not-real code. You have a history of posting poor quality questions, and unless you take the time to take the [tour], read the [help], and learn [ask] questions here, you may be blocked from posting new questions.

Comment: If you don't understand the program, the best person to ask to explain it to you is the person who wrote it.

Comment: `time` is a function. It expects to be called with a pointer to a `time_t`, but in this case it is being called with the number 0. This isn't quite the right way to do it. It should be  `time(nullptr);`or `time(NULL);` if your complier is a relic or set to compile for an older standard. In the old days, `NULL` was synonymous with 0, so   `time(0);` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to summarize how it does its job in one word, I'd say "poorly".

The standard library already has functions to do most of what it's doing, so if you just want to print out the current time in 12 hour format, you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main() { 
    time_t n = std::time(nullptr);
    tm now = *localtime(&n);

    std::cout << std::put_time(&now, "%H:%M:%S\n");
}
```

As for the loop, that's presumably to continue printing out the time (constantly updated) until you kill the program. Probably author couldn't figure out what to tell the compiler to say: "Until the end of time", so they just used "forever".

The `if` statements about `foo<10` seem to be to fill in a leading 0, so (for example) 8 minutes after 9 will print as `9:08` rather than `9:8` (but the code I have above handles that automatically).

As a side note: In my opinion (and I'm far from alone in this) `localtime` is rather poorly designed. The way I've used it above (immediately dereferencing the pointer it returns, and copying that `tm` into a new one) helps minimize the frequency of the problems it causes, but if you have it available, `localtime_r` is preferred.

Comment: There is no need to dereference a pointer to make a copy, only to convert that copy back to a pointer. You should replace `tm now = *localtime(&n); ... std::put_time(&now, ...)` with `... std::put_time(localtime(&n), ...)` or at least `tm* now = localtime(&n); ... std::put_time(now, ...)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I disagree. Yes, under the circumstances, just storing the pointer to its internal, statically allocated tm will work, but having it return a pointer to a statically allocated tm was a crappy design, and making use of that for anything except copying it into a tm of your own is a bad habit and should be avoided. If I were going to do anything different, it would be to suggest using localtime_r if available.

Comment: "*If I were going to do anything different, it would be to suggest using localtime_r if available*" - agreed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin When I ran the code you provided, the time was shown in the .exe, but it did not update continuously. Is there a way to modify that code so that it updates the time every second? Edit: I added a while loop around the code and inserted a clear screen in the loop to make the clock update every second.